# Filtering By blanks in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone give me some insight on how to Filter/Delete Blanks using VBA code? For some reason when I record a Macro to do this it is not allowing some of my custom functions built using VBA to hold their values.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code will delete out rows that have a blank in a selected column. The code below assumes the second column in your data is being tested for blanks. Let us know if you need additional assistance.

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()
    Dim rDataToProcess As Range

    Set rDataToProcess = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    'Field in the below method refers to the column that is being filtered, so the second colum
    rDataToProcess.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=""
    rDataToProcess.Offset(1).Resize(rDataToProcess.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete

    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to delete cells that are blank is to set a range, and use `Range([your range]).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete`

edit: If you want to delete the entire row, `Range([your range]).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

Answer (score 0):

Just as [@user3561813](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3561813/user3561813) said and please take a look at this [link](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-autofilter/) for more complicated filters such as multiple criteria, etc:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("AD1").AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:="", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="XXXX"
```

For example, the above code filters for both Blanks and "XXXX" fields

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub Blank_Cells_Filter()
'Apply filters to include or exclude blank cells

Dim lo As ListObject
Dim iCol As Long

'Set reference to the first Table on the sheet
Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)

'Set filter field
iCol = lo.ListColumns("Product").Index

'Blank cells – set equal to nothing
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="="

'Non-blank cells – use NOT operator <>
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:="<>"

End Sub
```