# Filter Out Blank Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently developing a macro to automate the cleaning process of an Excel worksheet. One of the subroutines aims to filter out specific terms, such as "Production," "Total," "Grand Total," and any blank values. It then proceeds to delete the filtered rows, leaving only the remaining rows intact. The current implementation successfully filters and deletes rows containing "Production," "Total," or "Grand Total" in the specified column. However, it fails to remove the rows with blank values ("(Blank)"). I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue or exploring alternative approaches to achieve the desired outcome. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Sub DeleteFilteredRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    
    ws.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Production", "Total", "Grand total", "(Blank)"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
   
    ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: You can filter for blank entries with `""`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520495/1024832

Comment: @Marc So I'd replace the "(Blank)" with ""?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to @Marc. All I needed to do was replace the "(Blank)" with ""

```
Sub DeleteFilteredRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    
    ws.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Production", "Total", "Grand total", ""), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
   
    ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! I'm glad it worked for you.